# Problem with debug program Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If I want debugging my program I see this error:

[image]

My Json File:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
    // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
    // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/DatingApp.API.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp.API",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
     ]
 }
```

I choose to Visual Studio Code .Net Core Launch Web when I see this error. I don't know who is the problem, perhaps with launch.json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the path must contain backslashes, if you are using any UNIX-like system, you must use normal slashes in the path.
Hope this helped.